# redirect directory using apache mod rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have directory named `/template/css`

The full url is `http://sitename.com/template/css`

I need this folder to be redirected using apache mod rewrite

from

```
http://sitename.com/template/css
```

to:

```
http://sitename.com/css
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to use `mod_rewrite`?  Why don't you just `Alias` `/css` to the location in the filesystem where the CSS files are actually stored?

Assuming that you *do* have a valid reason for doing this, the following should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/template/css(.*)$ /css$1
```